# Connect to MySQl In App Database In Azure Webjob

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a MySQL In-App Database in azure, I can connect fine in PHP on a normal webpage, my issue is I am trying to create a webjob, but when ever I try the web job file can't connect to the database and the connection string is empty.

I have tried to connect using the following:

```
getenv('MYSQLCONNSTR_bridgesConnection');

$_SERVER['MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb'];
```

Nither of these are bring back a connection string that I am able to use.

I have the code to break down the strings ect, it just that I can't get the database connection string, or find anywhere on how to get it into the webjob.

Answer (score 0):

After my test, the current feasible way is to send http request in webjob to get the `connection string` you want.

**Test step:**

1. Create a new application appsetting,`mytest`, and create a new webjob to read it.

[image]

2. Find webjob logs.

[image]

**Because both `Application settings` and `Connection strings` are derived from `App Config`, I think they cannot be read by `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, so the rest api method is used to get the parameters.**

3. Then I create a `Connection strings`,

[image]

4. Get connection strings by rest api.

[image]

You can [try it by yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listconnectionstrings#code-try-0).

Answer (score 0):

Connect to MySQL:

1. In Azure App services access the specific App Services you created
2. Then click on MySQL In App
3. In the MySQL In App pane, click on Manage to access phpAdmin

It’ll pop open a new window with the phpMyAdmin tool. Notice at the top of the window it’ll display the IP and port number your database is running on
Get your port number from the phpMyAdmin tool,

Access MySQL username and password:

To get your username and password. This information is in the MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini file in d:\home\data\mysql as displayed in the MySQL In App pane earlier.
To get this file, the best way is to go to Advanced Tools on the blade for your App Service.
You will find Advanced Tools under Development Tools

1. Under Development Tools, Click on Advanced Tools
2. In the Advanced Tools pane, click on Go in the Pane.
3. This will open Kudu Services in a new tab
4. In Kudu Services, click on Debug console at the top and choose CMD.

This will take you to the path and you’re GUI file list will load above with  the console window below.

5. Clicking on data folder in the GUI file list, will display aspnet and mysql folder.
6. Click on mysql to access location for MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini

Here you can download the file, open it with Notepad and get your username and password from the connection string stored inside.

You can also click on Edit in the GUI to view your password and username details, the content on edit looks like this

Database=databasename;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=username;Password=password